# How to refer to doc with constant link

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, word

I have few doc (word,pdf,excel) , i build table in text webpart on SPO with documents links like below:

```
+----------+---------+
| doc name | doc link|
+----------+---------+
|    A     | A.doc   | 
|    B     | B.pdf   |
+----------+---------+
```

in new document (x.doc or y.pdf)I want to add link to doc(A.doc),
new doc include:
"lorem ipsum....
... you find this documentation there (link)"

And few days later I change file A.doc to A1.doc but te doc name in table still will be A. So I need to change link to doc in table but I don't wona change link in doc x.doc or y.pdf and wherever this link is.

Ask is "what to do that not have to change link in all documents where this link is? Can I use this table on SharePoint Online (webpart text or SP List) or other references? Maybe SPO have const link?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Document ID on your site.

More info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/activate-and-configure-document-ids-in-a-site-collection-66345c77-f079-4104-ac7a-e25826849306

Comment: I use this solution and if I change document by delete old and upload new I give them old ID. more info:
https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-track-documents-in-sharepoint-using-document-id-feature/

Answer (score 0):

1.Per my test, if you change the document link from A.doc to A1.doc, you can still access the document through the previous link A.doc in the document x.doc.

2.I suggest you use Quick Links web part to store information.

Reference: [Use the Quick Links web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-quick-links-web-part-e1df7561-209d-4362-96d4-469f85ab2a82)

Comment: If you move doc to another place the link is the same but if you delete document and upload new then link is new.